# User Authentication - Device fingerprinting

Tags: firebase

We have to implement 2FA for user authentication. One is of course username/password but next we want to restrict the user when the device finger print is approved.

Is there any way to check this during authentication? I will created root/uid/devices to save the device fingerprint and status.

Cheers

Comment: What have you tried? Where exactly are you stuck? There are a lot of resources online about device fingerprinting in general.